# Will ReactJs app benefit in any way if I will include dom4 polyfill? do i need dom4 with ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom4

My app is fully done with ReactJs and there are no DOM manipulations outside React.

Will ReactJs app benefit in any way if I will include dom4 polyfill?

https://github.com/WebReflection/dom4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not affect React.
(Source: I work on React.)